# Input video data from C++ to QML Video Player

Tags: qt, qml, qmediaplayer, qiodevice

I am looking for a best way to implement a video player application in QML. Almost all QML examples are reading files from filesystem or web:

```
MediaPlayer {
    id: mediaplayer
    source: "groovy_video.mp4"
}

VideoOutput {
    anchors: parent.fill
    source: mediaplayer
}
```

I want to specify my own source for `MediaPlayer` - a C++ `QObject` derived class, that has an interface similar to `QIODevice`. That would be perfect for my needs. I need to preload video in parts and also to cache it for later use.

Is there an easy solution for my needs?
(I am using Qt 5.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you should be able to override any URL that is loaded by QML. The Qt 4 docs are a bit more explicit about this than Qt 5:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativenetwork.html

But the same should be similar for Qt 5:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlnetworkaccessmanagerfactory.html

e.g. you should be able to use a specific url schema for a custom source magic+videos://.... for your custom source.

Worst case scenario you have to inherit (and override some methods) from QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkReply (which inherits from QIODevice).

I have not played with this since qt4 but I assume a good starting point would be this:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-networkaccessmanagerfactory-example.html

I'm a bit outdated on this kind of stuff, but hopefully this helps.